# Ugly fonts in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 14.0 Windows 8.1

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts, jvm

I use [macType](https://code.google.com/p/mactype/) which renders fonts beautifully elsewhere except Intellij.

I tried to configure Intellij through these Java options

```
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings = On
-Dswing.aatext = True
```

but it did not help. I'm not sure why but Intelij does not let me choose Ubuntu Bold as the coding font. The rendering in sublime text 2 is much better. I'm using Windows 8.1. What to do?

I changed Parameters of `useSystemAAFontSettings` to lcd, but it did not help.
Although it seems to me that in Sublime Text the font is a little fuzzy, I use the font Ubuntu Bold, this wine macType?

In Intelij font appears to be fraying. The Ubuntu Mono font in Intelij with MacType does not look right - brackets [ and ] are poorly displayed.

Intelij Source Code:

[image]

Intelij Ubuntu Mono:

[image]

Sublime Text Ubuntu Bold:

[image]

Comment: Did you try with gdipp as mentioned below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java applications don't work well with MacType. Take a look at the discussion here:
https://code.google.com/p/mactype/issues/detail?id=53

You could try gdipp instead.
https://code.google.com/p/gdipp/. 
You may have to set the embolden parameter in its settings file to 6 or 7 atleast for all the glyphs to display correctly.

Intellij does not allow you to choose Ubuntu Bold because it is not a monospace font, but if you check *Show Only Monospaced fonts*, it should work.

Comment: Note that the gdipp project is from 2010 but works flawlessly for me in 2016 using PhpStorm 2016.2.

Comment: 2016.X Intellij based products also comes with a custom Open JDK 8 that Jetbrains has patched and backported fixes from JDK 9 to deal with font rendering. Open JDK uses freetype which in my opinion is better than the Windows font rendering. GDIPP also uses freetype, hence better font rendering.

Comment: The latest MacType also works very well with the latest Intellij. I've switched to using Mactype instead of gdipp now. http://www.mactype.net/