# UI Text not rendering properly with Intellij IDEA and MacType

Tags: intellij-idea, text

I wanted to make Intellij IDEA on windows look like the one on OS X Because in 
my opinion it looks much better, so I installed MacType, I was able to get the 
editor font render correctly, but when I change the UI font to match OS X's UI 
font, The text  gets cut off in some places. The font I am trying to use is 
Lucida Grande size 15. You can see it for yourself in the picture 
below:

Intellij UI Text getting cut: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jnda.png

But if I remove disable MacType rendering, everything works fine, but it looks bad.

Intellij UI Text without MacType rendering: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJEUl.png

I've tried changing MacType's settings, but nothing works!

I am on Windows 10 Creators Update with Intellij IDEA 2017.2
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you already check the following questions and answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061970/ugly-fonts-in-intellij-idea-community-edition-14-0-windows-8-1
https://superuser.com/questions/614960/how-to-fix-font-anti-aliasing-in-intellij-idea-when-using-high-dpi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself! Apparently if you open the mactype profile you are using with notepad, and paste the following text at the end of the file:

```
[Experimental@idea64.exe]
ClipBoxFix=1
```

Then all the fonts will render correctly. Note, this does not only work for Intellij IDEA, but also all other java applications and a few others. To achieve this, all you have to do is replace "idea64.exe" with the name of the app executable. An example is for the 32-bit version of Intellij, you would replace "idea64.exe" with "idea.exe".

More information can be found here: https://github.com/snowie2000/mactype/wiki/ClipBoxFix